# HTML footer navigation button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm beginner to coding, i was trying to achieve this footer example

[image: example]

and this is what i have

[image: my site]

what i want is when i click main menu it hides the links but i really don't know how to do it, i even tried some stuff with css but nothing, can someone please help me

also here is the site html from the footer part with css.

HTML

```css
/*Main Menu Button*/
.button{
    background-color: black;
    
}

/*footer*/
.site-footer{
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding:0px 0 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.site-footer hr{
  border-top-color:#bbb;
  opacity:0.5
}

.site-footer hr.small{
  margin:20px 0
}

.site-footer button{
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size:30px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin-top:10px;
  transform: translateX(3%);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.site-footer a{
  color: white;
}

.site-footer a:hover{
  color:red;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.footer-links{
  padding-left:0;
  list-style:none;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-links li{
  display:block;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

.footer-links a{
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.footer-links a:active,.footer-links a:focus,.footer-links a:hover{
  color:red;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.footer-links.inline li{
  display:inline-block
}

.copyright-text{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(3%);
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    
}
```

```html
<footer class="site-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <button class="button">Main Menu</button>
      <div class="Footer-list">
        <div class="menu-tab ozen">
          <ion-icon name="chevron-up-outline"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <ul class="footer-links">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Artwork</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Commissions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Prints</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <p class="copyright-text">© 2020 samidraws</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: For someone to help you at this stage, they will need to basically do the job for you, which is not what SO is about. You need a more specific problem. Do you understand javascript event handlers? Are you going to use jQuery or some other framework or just pure javascript? If you don't know what an onClick handler is, then you may need to do more study before you're ready to post the question.

Comment: To point you in roughly the right direction, you need some javascript to handle the click event on the main menu, then in the handler you need to set some styling or class on the items you want to hide.

Comment: look into html script tags and creating a js function that will alter your site when something else is clicked. If you try something and cant get it to work, update your post with what you tried and people can help from there.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody wanted to help but I found the answer myself, what I was trying to do is called an collapsible footer it was actually simple I only had problem with "display: none", so here is my collapsible footer:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible{
    background-color: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
    
}

.collapsible:focus {outline:0;}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  
}

/*footer*/
.site-footer{
  background-color: black;
  padding:0px 0 20px;
}


.footer-links{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
    
}

.footer-links.hide{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  transform: translateX(0%)
}


.site-footer hr{
  border-top-color:#bbb;
  opacity:0.5
}

.site-footer hr.small{
  margin:20px 0
}

.site-footer button{
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size:30px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin-top:10px;
  transform: translateX(3%);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.site-footer a{
  color: white;
}

.site-footer a:hover{
  color:red;
  text-decoration:none;
}


.footer-links li{
  display:block;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

.footer-links a{
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.footer-links a:active,.footer-links a:focus,.footer-links a:hover{
  color:red;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.footer-links.inline li{
  display:inline-block
}

.copyright-text{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(3%);
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0,
          maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    
    <!-- OWN STYLESHEET -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <!-- TAB TITLE NAME -->
       <title> Sami Draws </title>
    <!-- LOGOS -->
       </script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aldrich&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
       
  </head>
    <!-- BODY -->
<body>
<header>
</header>

<!-- collapsible footer-->
<footer class="site-footer">
            <button type="button" class="collapsible">Main Menu</button>
            <div class="content">
            <ul class="footer-links">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Artwork</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Commissions</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Prints</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <p class="copyright-text">© 2020 samidraws</p>
          </div>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
        
    
</footer>


</body>
</html>
```